# UTC Incorrect while RTC Okay

Tags: debian, ntp

I have installed Debian 8 standard edition on my mini-pc, and usually found the following kernel message

```
[146262.743546]  INFO:  rcu-sched detected stalls on CPUs/tasks:  {} (detected by 0,  t 15227 jiffies,  g 54023,  c 54022,  q-0)
```

Every time this message appear, system time goes wrong. Using the command

```
hwclock; timedatectl
```

, I retrieve both hardware clock and system time. The former one is pretty accurate, while the latter one is totally wrong, saying a number of hours delay. I have enabled NTP for timedatectl, but there is no improvement found.

May anyone help? Many thanks. ^^

Comment: You can check if `ntp` is working properly by reading `ntpq -p`.  Some of the systemd changes (in particular for ntp) I've found to be buggy, making ntp stop working.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! I think I won't install ntp package, as I am required to use native ones.

Comment: Your time may be badly out of sync, and perhaps stopping `ntpd`, running `ntpdate -b 0.north-america.pool.ntp.org` then starting `ntpd` again would fix the problem.